# Passing variables around a GUI (using globals)?

Tags: python, user-interface, global

I have a short program using Tkinter with two main buttons: Load Files, and Run Process.

Load Files creates four lists of a few thousand objects each.
Run Process runs my algorithm on these lists and generates a report for the user.

My question is: In general, where should these lists reside? Right now I have them as globals, but as we're always told, that's bad practice. I *feel* like this is an appropriate place to use globals, but is there a better way?

My main function is:

```
def main():
    root.mainloop()
```

Load Files starts as:

```
def load_files():
    global key_map
    global ser_events
    global scada_events
    global beta_dict
    and then load the files...
```

Run Process starts as:

```
def run_process():
    global ser_events
    global scada_events
    global beta_dict
    and then do the process stuff...
```

Comment: your application should be a class ... these should be data members of that class ... that said theres old saying that goes "if it aint broke dont fix it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking at [this site](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm). The way this example is set up, the tkinter app is a class. Your `load_files()` and `run_process()` functions will be functions of the class, and instead of using global variable (stay away from globals in python!), the variables will be class properties.

Unfortunately this would require a rewrite of your code, however it promotes good programming techniques, and your code will be much neater and readable :)